# Remove Title Bar from Windows Form (Windows 10 style)

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a very simple class which inherits from System.Windows.Forms.Form and removes the [WS_CAPTION](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/czada357.aspx)  window style. It works in Windows XP & 7 perfectly. In windows 10 a piece of the titlebar is still drawn and it ends up looking ugly when using a custom titlebar control.

I know there are likely several ways to accomplish this kind of look, but I've chosen this for multiple reasons. I'm not interested in the alternative methods--that's not the intention of my question here.

**My question is what is causing such a difference between the way this is rendered in windows 10 vs windows 7?** The difference is not merely stylistic. It appears that the titlebar is still being rendered in some capacity even though the WS_CAPTION flag has been removed.

```
class BorderlessForm : System.Windows.Forms.Form
{
    protected override System.Windows.Forms.CreateParams CreateParams
    {
        get
        {
            var _CreateParams = base.CreateParams;
            _CreateParams.Style &= ~0x00C00000; // remove WS_CAPTION
            return _CreateParams;
        }
    }
}
```

Windows 7 screenshot (desired appearance consistent with MSDN description):

[image]

Windows 10 screenshot (undesirable appearance inconsistent with MSDN description):

[image]

Comment: you're using winforms which is an outdated presentation technology unlikely to work in a predictable manner in later versions of windows.  Use WPF.

Comment: Show me MSDN documentation of winforms being deprecated and I'll mark that as the answer...

Comment: I didn't say it was being deprecated.  I just said it was outdated.  It's legacy.

Comment: @rory.ap Are you saying WPF can create windows that are not bound to Windows styles and similar stuff? Come on, it's the same old good Windows OS around.

Comment: You are not supposed to do it this way, the window is too tall, use  ControlBox = False and Text = "".  Doesn't otherwise fix this problem, it is a very strange one.  I think I first saw this go wrong at Win 10.0.10586.  It *looks* like WM_NCCALCSIZE is not handled properly but it isn't one that Winforms tinkers with.  Hmm.  Next major release fixes it hopefully, build number 14393 (aka anniversary edition) was released on Aug 2.

Comment: @Hans  Exactly where I was hoping this would go. I've been playing with WmNCCalcSize to find a possible override fix, but it is getting a bit hackish. `Controlbox = false` gives the same result that I've shown here.

Comment: you draw using tablelayoutpanel that above row fill out you want color

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are observing is not a title bar but sizing border.

> **My question is what is causing such a difference between the way this is rendered in windows 10 vs windows 7?**

The cause is different look and feel implementation on different versions of Windows.

In case you are interested how to get rid of the sizing border even on Windows 10: Remove the `WS_THICKFRAME` flag.

Alternatively (and perhaps more preferable) you can change your form's `FormBorderStyle` to some other value. Test whatever works best for you.

However there is nothing what defines the overall form border precisely. It's up to the look and feel (theme). Technically you cannot expect that form's border won't differ under different implementation. You can only ensure by testing.